# Splitting SQL Query Data into Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query I am running, My data so far shows as below.

| Open Files | Closed Files |
| --- | --- |
| 1186 | 371 |

However, I need the data split into rows by Teams. E.g

| Team | Open Files | Closed Files |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7563 | 112 |
| 2 | 2365 | 160 |
| 3 | 1258 | 99 |

The teams are in another table called UserGroup. I just have no idea how I can bring the Team into the query to make the data split by the teams.

Thanks

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT (AccountID)
FROM tblaccount
WHERE CloseDate IS NULL) AS Open Files,
(SELECT COUNT (AccountID)
FROM tblaccount
WHERE CloseDate IS NOT NULL) AS Closed Files
```

Comment: Neither do we, you haven't showed us how the data is stored nor how it should be joined.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your tblaccount contains Team column. Then it's as easy as:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN CloseDate IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS openFiles
, COUNT(CASE WHEN CloseDate IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS closedFiles
, Team
FROM tblAccount
GROUP BY Team
```